# HTML Formatting in SMTPClient for Gmail

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Im using SMTPClient for sending mails with html formatting to Gmail but the mail received is shown in plain text..

this is my code:

```
SmtpClient SmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            using (MailMessage MailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                MailAddress FromMailAddress = new MailAddress(_Cred_userName);
                MailAddress ToMailAddress = new MailAddress(_toAddress);
                SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_Cred_userName, _Cred_passWord);
                SmtpClient.Port = _Cred_port;
                SmtpClient.Host = _Cred_host;
                MailMessage.From = FromMailAddress;
                MailMessage.To.Add(ToMailAddress);
                MailMessage.Subject = _subject;
                MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                MailMessage.Body = _body;                    
                foreach (var items in _attachmentCol)
                {
                    Attachment att = new Attachment(items);
                    MailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);
                }

                SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage);

            }
```

**_body**  contains:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .cs7CED571B{text-align:left;text-indent:0pt;padding:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}
        .cs5B0A87D4{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:12pt; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; text-decoration: line-through;}
        .csB86C8CFE{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; }
        .csA62DFD6A{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:12pt; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; }
        .cs36E2AA4C{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:8pt; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span><p class="cs7CED571B"><span class="cs5B0A87D4">T</span><span class="csB86C8CFE">e</span><span class="csA62DFD6A">s</span><sup><span class="cs36E2AA4C">t</span></sup></p></span></body>
```

**Gmail** only recieved

> Test

do the gmail has their own html formatting for emails? :)
is there any other way to show html formats in gmail?

im getting **_body** html data from **DevExpress RichTextEditor.htmlText**

thanks in advance for the help.. :)

Comment: hello.. just a follow up for my question.. :)